# Keep values selected after form submission

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, forms

Consider:

```
<form method="get" action="">
   <select name="name">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
   </select>
   <select name="location">
      <option value="x">x</option>
      <option value="y">y</option>
   </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

On submitting the form, how do I make sure that the selected values remain selected in the dropdowns? This form is inside WordPress (PHP).

Comment: There is not benefit in repeating the option's text as its `value`.  You can safely remove those redundant declarations and all form submission process and clientside operations will still work flawlessly.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To avoid many if-else structures, let JavaScript do the trick automatically:

```
<select name="name" id="name">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('name').value = "<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>";
</script>

<select name="location" id="location">
  <option value="x">x</option>
  <option value="y">y</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('location').value = "<?php echo $_GET['location'];?>";
</script>
```

Comment: Strange solution IMO- Introducing javascript to save a couple lines of PHP makes no sense.

Comment: @Yarin: Agreed, a quick solution, in office by that time, no much time :(

Comment: great solution but kind of sketchy. used on LEMP stack and i was unable to reload nginx. after debugging with sudo tail /var/log/nginx/error.log the errors were directly at these lines and after removing code i was able to reload just fine

Comment: value is correct but i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"
Select name matches...idk

Answer (score 31):

```
<select name="name">
   <option <?php if ($_GET['name'] == 'a') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="a">a</option>
   <option <?php if ($_GET['name'] == 'b') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If the `option` tags are being generated in code (and if they aren't, then why not?) you can just put the check within the loop.

Answer (score 9):

After trying all these "solutions", nothing work. I did some research on [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) before and remember there was explanation of keeping values about radio.

But it also works for the `Select` option. See below for an example. Just try it out and play with it.

```
<?php
    $example = $_POST["example"];
?>
<form method="post">
    <select name="example">
        <option <?php if (isset($example) && $example=="a") echo "selected";?>>a</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($example) && $example=="b") echo "selected";?>>b</option>
        <option <?php if (isset($example) && $example=="c") echo "selected";?>>c</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Since WordPress already uses jQuery you can try something like this:

```
var POST=<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>;
for(k in POST){
  $("#"+k).val(POST[k]);
}
```

Comment: Are there any security concerns with using this type of method?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using WordPress (as is the case with the OP), you can use the [`selected`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/) function.

```
<form method="get" action="">
  <select name="name">
    <option value="a" <?php selected( isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '', 'a' ); ?>>a</option>
    <option value="b" <?php selected( isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '', 'b' ); ?>>b</option>
  </select>
  <select name="location">
    <option value="x" <?php selected( isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : '', 'x' ); ?>>x</option>
    <option value="y" <?php selected( isset($_POST['location']) ? $_POST['location'] : '', 'y' ); ?>>y</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I think it is the best solution for WordPress. It works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript only solution:

```
var tmpParams = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substr(1)).split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < tmpParams.length; i++) {
    var tmparr = tmpParams[i].split("=");
    var tmp = document.getElementsByName(tmparr[0])[0];
    if (!!tmp){
        document.getElementsByName(tmparr[0])[0].value = tmparr[1];
    }
}
```

Or if you are using jQuery you can replace

```
 var tmp = document.getElementsByName(tmparr[0])[0];
 if (!!tmp){
     document.getElementsByName(tmparr[0])[0].value = tmparr[1];
 }
```

with:

```
 $('*[name="'+tmparr[0]+'"]').val(tmparr[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution for keep selected value in dropdown:

```
<form action="<?php echo get_page_link(); ?>" method="post">
    <select name="<?php echo $field_key['key']; ?>" onchange="javascript: 
       submit()">
    <option value="">All Category</option>
    <?php 
    foreach( $field['choices'] as $key => $value ){ 
       if($post_key==$key){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" selected><?php echo $value; ?></option>
<?php
   }else{?>
  <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>
 <?php }
  }?>
 </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```
<label for="reason">Reason:</label>
<select name="reason" size="1" id="name" >
    <option value="NG" selected="SELECTED"><?php if (!(strcmp("NG", $_POST["reason"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>Selection a reason below</option>
    <option value="General"<?php if (!(strcmp("General", $_POST["reason"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>General Question</option>
    <option value="Account"<?php if (!(strcmp("Account", $_POST["reason"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Account Question</option>
    <option value="Other"<?php if (!(strcmp("Other", $_POST["reason"]))) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?>>Other</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work in WordPress much, but for forms outside of WordPress, this works well.

#### PHP

```
location = "";  // Declare variable

if($_POST) {
    if(!$_POST["location"]) {
        $error .= "Location is required.<br />"; // If not selected, add string to error message
     }else{
        $location = $_POST["location"];          // If selected, assign to variable
     }
```

#### HTML

```
<select name="location">
    <option value="0">Choose...</option>
    <option value="1" <?php if (isset($location) && $location == "1") echo "selected" ?>>location 1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if (isset($location) && $location == "2") echo "selected" ?>>location 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
```

with this line:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Submit/Reload" class="submit" onclick="history.go(-1);">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="name">
    <?php $options = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
        foreach($options as $o){                            
            if($o == $_GET['name']) $attr="selected='true'";
            else $attr = "";
            echo "<option value='{$o}' {$attr}>{$o}</option>";
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

We can create an array of option before hand and only use simple if/else to check if selected or not. If you want different values for data and different value for displaying option you can use associative arrays too.

```
<select name="name">
    <?php $options = ["a"=>"Option A", "b"=>"Option B", "c"=>"Option C", "d"=>"Option D", "e"=>"Option E"];
        foreach($options as $index=>$o){                            
            if($index == $_GET['name']) $attr="selected='true'";
            else $attr = "";
            echo "<option value='{$index}' {$attr}>{$o}</option>";
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="get" action="">
 <select name="name" value="<?php echo $_GET['name'];?>">
   <option value="a">a</option>
   <option value="b">b</option>
 </select>
 <select name="location" value="<?php echo $_GET['location'];?>">
   <option value="x">x</option>
   <option value="y">y</option>
 </select>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You need to set the `selected` attribute on the option you want selected.