# How to keep form values after post

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to find what the easiest way to keep form values after post. I am really trying to have to keep from learning ajax right this second for the one form, Plus I am not sure how hard it would be to implement ajax into my already existing google map page. So I am trying to find a way to retain the values of two date fields after submit has been pushed

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission

Comment: wait are you trying to re-populate the form after a post or are you trying to reuse the values in the form after submit? like on different pages?

Comment: Do you want to just maintain access to the values? Or do you want the page to persist the values (assuming you are posting to the same page)?

Comment: I would like to either re-populate or keep the values there. I assume that to keep the values I have to use Ajax, so I would like to repopulate so the user doesnt have to remember what their selection was.

Comment: Shoudn't be marked as duplicate with the other question which belongs to wordpress.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you are looking to just repopulate the fields with the values that were posted in them, then just echo the post value back into the field, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="myField1" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField1']) ? $_POST['myField1'] : '' ?>" />
```

Comment: @Kenji CSRF Token... And htmlspecialchars.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would say what to do, not just "NO. Don't do that."  Use htmlspecialchars($_POST[ ..

Comment: That's the basic idea. In addition you should clean the submitted data to get rid of coding characters.

Comment: This works, but should be a problem on `select` tag however

Comment: It works in the `select` tag. add a second  `<option selected . . . /> <?php echo . . . ?></option>` where the select - option text would go.

Answer (score 7):

you can save them into a $_SESSION variable and then when the user calls that page again populate all the inputs with their respective session variables.

Comment: storing them into a $_SESSION would kill the server. cookies or the chosen answer are the best ways.

Comment: @zeeks I'm a beginner in php. Why will it kill the server? Could you please clarify?