# How to send form errors back to the form via $_POST when redirected for processing

Tags: php, post

I have a form in `contact.php` with a considerable amount of inputs.

this form will be mailed using the php `mail()` function providing the captcha is correct and the input values follow the regex.

the action for the form is `"mailer.php"` and the method is `post`

on the `mailer.php`, validation is checked and captcha verification etc. But if the user enters the wrong captcha, they are redirected back to the form.

Where ALL the data they just entered is CLEARED!

I used to redirect with a query string and the`$_GET` array.

But I cant do that for this form as there is a lot of data including many textareas etc.

So how can I send this data back to the form on error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form values should not clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484299/form-values-should-not-clear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the user input information as `$_SESSION` variables. Dont forget to include `session_start();` to initiate the session.

Answer (score 2):

You should design the flow like :-

1. form (accepting a set of default values)
2. when user submit the form to mailer.php

   - necessary checking
   - if success, proceed to mail

     - complete then redirect to whatever place
   - if fail

     - require the form again
     - pass the $_POST as the default values

Basically, don't do redirect when fail (only upon success)