# Can you make certain variable values persist across 2 instances of a form?

Tags: php, forms, variables, persistence

[image: result entry form]

Below is a form that allows me to key in dog show results, it works fine for one dog at a time.
There may be many dogs showing in the same class, the first 3 fields are common to all dogs showing in the same class. Having to fill them in for each dog slows down data entry and is a real pain.

Is there a simple way of ensuring that the values selected in the first 3 fields are not reset when I click on "Submit"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep form values after post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198304/how-to-keep-form-values-after-post)

Comment: Is it an option to use `value='<?php $_POST['dogStuff']'; ?>` on the relevant input fields? This would use the value that they put in in the previous form into the current form.