# HTML - $_GET textarea clear everything if contains INTRO char

Tags: php, html, forms

Related to this question: 
[Keep values selected after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission)

I have a form with some inputs, and a Textarea field.

Well, the form works perfectly after submit the form, I get back all parameters in its respective inputs. But if the Textarea contains text with intros, for example:

```
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit ametLorem ipsum,
dolor sit ametLorem ipsum, dolor sit am
etLorem ipsum, dolor sit ametLorem ipsu
m, dolor sit ametLorem.

Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet
```

The form after sending appears in blank, without any refilled input.

Here is the code

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" method="POST">
<table><tr><td>
<textarea name="txt_area" id="txt_area"cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><input type="text" size="40" name="name" id="name" />
</td></tr></table></form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("name").value = "'.$_GET["name"].'";
document.getElementById("txt_area").value = "'.$_GET["txt_area"].'";
</script>
```

Comment: you need add echo php in print $_GET... <?php echo $_GET["name"] ?>

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using php 
try this:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = "<?php echo($_GET['name']); ?>";
document.getElementById("txt_area").value = "<?php echo($_GET['txt_area']); ?>";
```

instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("name").value = "'.$_GET["name"].'";
document.getElementById("txt_area").value = "'.$_GET["txt_area"].'";
```