# Keep value selected even after form submission in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

This is my php code:

```
<select name="month" id="select1">
    <option value="">Select Month</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($monthArray as $month) {
        $monthPadding = str_pad($month, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $fdate = date("M", strtotime("2016-$monthPadding-01"));
        echo '<option name="month" value="'.$monthPadding.'">'.$fdate.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

I want to keep the selected month in dropdown list even after submiting form. Now dropdown list shows months from april to november (apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov).

Answer (score 2):

Remove your below code..

```
echo '<option name="month" value="'.$monthPadding.'">'.$fdate.'</option>';
```

And Replace it with the one below...

```
echo '<option name="month" value="'.$monthPadding.'"';
if($_POST['month']==$monthPadding){
   echo ' selected';
}
echo '>'.$fdate.'</option>';
```

Use the code below before your dropdown...

```
$month = '';
if(isset($_POST['month'])){
    $month = $_POST['month'];
}
```

And use `$month` when comparing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps. It's basically the same. You send data with GET and "get" them back with js.

[Keep values selected after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission)