# set selected value of <select> into what I choose lat time before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Here's the process I want to realize:

1.on index page, select one option from the list of items;

2.submit form,directing to the index page ;

3.`select` label showing the default value which equals what I chose in step 1.

e.g.

```
<html>
  <select>
    <option value="1">1<option/>
    <option value="2">2<option/>
    <option value="3">3<option/>
  </select>
</html>
```

On index page if I chose 1 ,and submit it and the page is submitted to itself(the index page).Now,on the index page, `<option value="1">1<option/>` is selected by default.

I don't know which correct direction I should go and I haven't found any solutions from the Internet yet.Anybody has any ideas??

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep values selected after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission)

Comment: Thanks,I found the answer from the above website.@Mark

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP function and javascript onchange:

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["myselect"])) {
    $myselect = $_POST["myselect"];
}
else {
    $myselect = 1;  
}

function isselected(A,B) {
    if ($A == $B){
        return "selected";
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
?>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<select name="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit();">
<option value="1" <?php echo isselected(1,$myselect) ?> >1<option/>
<option value="2" <?php echo isselected(2,$myselect) ?> >2<option/>
<option value="3" <?php echo isselected(3,$myselect) ?> >3<option/>
</select>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Name attribute is must for form elements .otherwise element value would not passed to server.

**2nd :** Check the post value and add the selected attribute for that option like below .

```
<select name="select1">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="1" <?php echo (isset($_POST['select1']) && $_POST['select1']==1 )? 'selected':''; ?>>1</option>
<option value="2" <?php echo (isset($_POST['select1']) && $_POST['select1']==2 )? 'selected':''; ?>>2</option>
<option value="3" <?php echo (isset($_POST['select1']) && $_POST['select1']==3 )? 'selected':''; ?>>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

coudn't understand your question quite well but..If you want to select any other value by default, once the page comes back to the index page, you will have to send the selected value back to the index page.

```
<html>
<select>
<option value="1">1<option/>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2<option/>
<option value="3">3<option/>
</select>
</html>
```

The above would select option 2, so you just have to set it accordingly.