# Selected dropdown always changed after submit

Tags: codeigniter, dropdown, selected

i have a dropdown for month and year , but after submit this dropdown alwas back to default (january)  . i used Codeigniter

```
<label>Bulan</label><br>
                  <select name="bulan">
                      <!-- <option value="">Pilih</option> -->

                      <option value="01">Januari</option>
                      <option value="02">Februari</option>
                      <option value="03">Maret</option>
                      <option value="04">April</option>
                      <option value="05">Mei</option>
                      <option value="06">Juni</option>
                      <option value="07">Juli</option>
                      <option value="08">Agustus</option>
                      <option value="09">September</option>
                      <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                      <option value="11">November</option>
                      <option value="12">Desember</option>
                  </select>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                          document.getElementById('bulan').value = "<?php echo $_GET['bulan'];?>";
                        </script>
                </div>
                <div class="tahun" align="center">
                <?php
                $now=date('Y');
                echo "<select name=tahun>";
                for ($a=2010;$a<=$now;$a++)
                {
                     echo "<option value='$a'>$a</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  document.getElementById('tahun').value = "<?php echo $_GET['tahun'];?>";
                </script>
                <br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit">
                </div>
              </form>
```

i referenced this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission)
 but its not work ,can someone help me ?
and its my controler

```
 public function view_status(){


    $year = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $month = $this->input->post('bulan');

    $this->data['hasil']=$this->app_model->status_data($year,$month);

    $this->load->view('view_status',$this->data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `view_status` controller :

```
public function view_status(){


    $year = $this->input->post('tahun');
    $month = $this->input->post('bulan');

    $this->data['hasil'] = $this->app_model->status_data($year,$month);
    $this->data['bulan'] = $month;
    $this->data['tahun'] = $year;

    $this->load->view('view_status',$this->data);

}
```

Edit select `bulan` script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('bulan').value = "<?php echo $bulan;?>";
</script>
```

Edit select `tahun` script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('tahun').value = "<?php echo $tahun;?>";
</script>
```

Comment: its work but make my table error :(  . Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: ok i change it [hasil] and this month its work , but this year is didnt work , its because my php script ? or where i can paste the Js script ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, separating the `month` and `year` data

Comment: It is better to use form_dropdown([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[, $extra = '']]]]) function to generate the Select control and select the default value instead of using JS to select the default value. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=select#form_dropdown

Comment: @Nish he/she have a static hardcoded array list, doing that would be requiring extra work of assigning data to array first

Answer (score 0):

your JS is `getElementById` but in your dropdown there is no id, update your dropdown as below

```
<select name="bulan" id="bulan">
...
...
</select>
```

Comment: i changed it , but its still didnt work , are u have more solution ?

Comment: Hi I just want to ask you one thing, after submit your are redirecting to the above form page is it?

Comment: document.getElementById('bulan').value = "     this value is empty

Comment: after submitting a dropdown I reload the page because the submit results affect the data I display

Comment: then check your for method POST or GET and update $_GET['bulan'] based on that. if still not working try to check  $_GET['bulan']/$_POST['bulan'] value