# Keep data checked even on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I am getting all the data in the form using Javascript because the checked data can either be updated or deleted.

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Availability</th>
        <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
   <?php
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        extract($row);
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="selected_id[]" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /></td>
        <th><?php echo $item; ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php } }else{ ?>
        <tr><td colspan="3">No records found.</td></tr> 
    <?php } ?>
    <form name="updateForm" method="post" action="updateproduct.php">
        <select name="availability" id="availability" required onchange="enableButton()">
           <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value=''>Select an option.</option>
           <option value="Available today">Available today</option>
           <option value="Not available today">Not available today</option>
        </select>
     </form>
     <input type="submit" id="btn_update" value="Update Records" /> 
     <input type="submit" id="btn_delete" value="Delete Records" />
</table>

<form name="deleteForm" method="post" action="deleteselected.php" onsubmit="return deleteAlert();"></form>
```

This is the Javascript that I've used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function enableButton()
                        {
                            var selectelem = document.getElementById('availability');
                            var btnelem = document.getElementById('btn_update');
                            btnelem.disabled = !selectelem.value;
                        }   
                        function setFormValuesAndSubmit(form) {
                            const checked = $("#resultTable input[name='selected_id[]']:checked");
                            if (!checked.length) {
                                alert("Please select an item.");
                                return;
                            }

                            form = $(form);
                            form.find("[name='selected_id[]']").remove();
                            checked.each(function(){
                                $("<input/>", {type: "hidden", name: "selected_id[]", value: $(this).val()}).appendTo(form);
                            });
                            form.submit();
                        }
                        $("#btn_update").click(function() {
                            setFormValuesAndSubmit(document.updateForm);
                        });
                        $("#btn_delete").click(function(){
                            setFormValuesAndSubmit(document.deleteForm);
                        });
</script>
```

My question is how can I keep the data checked still checked even when the form is submitted? Is there any way that I can use php for this? I am not familiar in JSON

Comment: I think you need to make some async requests (i.e AJAX), as i can see when you submit the form, the page gets refreshed, right ? if so, you will lose data upon submission

Comment: Is there any way that we can use php to do that? Im a bit new and not familiar in JSON.

Comment: As you are asking php to build your form, you have to ask him to check the checkboxes (html attribute "checked" of the checkboxes). It will get them from the request.

Comment: Well, you can do that by getting data from your requests and use it to check and select the controls (checkbox -> checked attribute, select  -> selected attribute)

Comment: Have a look at this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission

Comment: Will that also be applicable on a checkbox?

Comment: yes, add the checked attribute when you need the checkbox to be checked.